# Make Custom Filter and WebSecurityConfig run after Actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to implement Stateless Authentication using a custom filter that extends `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`. The filter works fine locally.

We have actuator defined which gets triggered during deployment. Since the custom filter depends on REST APIs it fails since actuator is just calling `/health` endpoint.

Is there are a way to defer `WebSecurityConfig` and its associated `CustomFilter` after the actuator call. In other words, actuator is called before Spring Security filter chain?

`WebSecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/healthcheck/**", "/health/**", "/actuator/health");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        http.addFilterAfter(customAuthFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthFilter customAuthFilter() throws Exception {
        CustomAuthFilter customAuthFilter = new CustomAuthFilter();
        customAuthFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return customAuthFilter;
    }

}
```

Note: `CustomFilter` is a validation filter to validate header values.

`CustomFilter.java`:

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

... business logic
}
```

Spring Boot Version: 2.2

Comment: No and it would beat the security purpose. Just configure security to permit all access on `/actuator` urls.

Comment: Can you specify the Http security configure method for permitting actuator endpoints